# Can I use 'throw {}' and stack trace is right in promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

I tried two way as below

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reject()
  })
  .catch(() => {
    throw {
      name: 'a',
      message: 'b'
    }
  })

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reject()
  })
  .catch(() => {
    throw new Error({
      name: 'a',
      message: 'b'
    });
  })
```

[image]

'`throw {}`'have a problem, is stack trace is not right

stack trace of the '`throw new Error()`' is right, but can't throw message as json

Can I use '`throw {}`' and stack trace is right?

Answer (score 0):

The `stack` property only exists on `Error` objects. The first parameter of the `Error` constructor is a string though, so if you pass an object to it it'll be stringified. You could do

```
  throw Object.assign(new Error("message"), {
     // properties
   });
```

to throw an error object with custom properties.